# Trigger axispointer function on existing chart js via console

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, visualization, echarts

I have a chart js similar to that in echarts docs
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#axisPointer
I want to trigger this axispointer from web console at a point in the graph that I specify. Is that possible? If so, how?

Is there a way to invoke any chart function for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it for the demo website that I mentioned earlier

```
var ch=echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-panel')) 

ch.dispatchAction({ 

    type:'showTip', 

    seriesIndex:0, 

    dataIndex:0});
```

Works somewhat for axispointers.